# Why is unitary diagonalization works?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I've been told that if you take an Hermitian matrix, find it's eigenvectors, normalize them and write them as columns of a matrix, $P$ then:

$$P^{-1}AP = D$$

Where (Magically) $D = \text{Diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$ ($\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$).

So I really want to use this algorithm but first I wish to understand why does this magic works?

Comment: If we assume that there is a basis of eigenvectors of $A,$ then it's very easy to check that, with the definitions from the question, we have indeed $P^{-1}AP= D.$ Regarding the existence of such a basis of eigenvectors of $A,$ see for example [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/diag_11.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

By [Schur decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition), every square matrix $A$ is unitarily similar to an upper triangular matrix $U$. In particular if $A$ is Hermitian, then
$$U^* = (Q^* A Q)^* = Q^* A^* Q = Q^* A Q = U$$
which shows that $U$ is a diagonal matrix.